# Is the fiber of a fibration over a $1$-dimensional manifold a trivial line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let  $X$  and $Y$   be two complex manifolds, $\rm{dim}X=n\geq 2$, $\rm{dim}Y=1$,  and $f:X\to Y$   a surjective holomorphic  map. Assume $f^{-1}(y)$ is a  fiber with $\rm{dim}=n-1$.

> Question: **Is the holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(y))$ trivial, i.e. $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(y))\cong \mathcal{O}_X$?**  (Here the $f^{-1}(y)$ is considered as an effective  divisor on $X$.)

**Some explanation:**  If the base $Y$ is a domain in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, then the divisor $f^{-1}(y)$ is **cut out by a single holomorphic function**, which gives that $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(y))\cong\mathcal{O}_X$.
But what if the base $Y$ is not a domain in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$? For example, **let $Y=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $y={\infty}\in \mathbb{P}^1$.**

Comment: This is very unclear. You're repeatedly asking about the value of a sheaf on a non-open subset - this is not something that's traditionally supported.

Comment: @KReiser I also have no idea what they;'re talking about, but I think they mean $\mathcal{O}(D)$ where $D=f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis ahh, that's a much more reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$, $Y=\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ the natural projection map onto the first factor. Then, $f^{-1}(\infty)=\{\infty\}\times\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ and so $\mathcal{O}(f^{-1}(y))\cong \mathcal{O}(1,0)$. @KReiser Feel free to answer if OP clarifies--I won't be able to for a few days.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, you are right.  The $f^{-1}(y)$ is considered as an effective  divisor on $X$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you.  I don't know what is the $\mathcal{O}(1,0)$. Can you explain  it more?

Comment: @LelongWang I believe $\mathcal{O}(1,0)$ means the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ along the first projection